# Replace string with quotes, brackets, braces, and slashes in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string where I am trying to replace `["{\"` with `[{"` and all `\"` with `"`.

I am struggling to find the right syntax in order to do this, does anyone have a solid understanding of how to do this?

I am working with JSON, and I am inserting a string into the JSON properties. This caused it to put a single quotes around my inserted data from my variable, and I need those single quotes gone. I tried to do `json.dumps()` on the data and do a string replace, but it does not work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some context to your question (click on **edit** after it) to understand your motivation and to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/356878).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` method.
See documentation and examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend maybe posting more of your code below so we can suggest a better answer. Just based on the information you have provided, I would say that what you are looking for are escape characters. I may be able to help more once you provide us with more info!

Answer (score 0):

Use the target/replacement strings as arguments to `replace()`.

The general format is `mystring = mystring.replace("old_text", "new_text")`

Since your target strings have backslashes, you also probably want to use raw strings to prevent them from being interpreted as special characters.

```
mystring = "something"
mystring = mystring.replace(r'["{\"', '[{"')
mystring = mystring.replace(r'\"', '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

if its two characters you want to replace then you have to first check for first character and then the second(which should be present just after the first one and so on) and shift(shorten the whole array by 3 elements in first case whenever the condition is satisfied and in the second case delete \ from the array.
You can also find particular substring by using inbuilt function and replace it  by using replace() function to insert the string you want in its place